# Delphi - why does this function work if the class is not created?

Tags: function, class, delphi

Consider this class:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type

  TTeste = class
  private
    texto: string;
  public
    function soma(a, b: integer): string;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  teste: TTeste;
begin
  teste:= nil;
  teste.texto:= '';//access violation
  showmessage(teste.soma(5, 3));//no access violation
end;

{ TTeste }

function TTeste.soma(a, b: integer): string;
begin
  result:= (a+b).ToString;
end;

end.
```

should it really work? why? the var crashed but the function doesnt, does it works like a class funtion?

Answer (score 13):

This works because you are not attempting to access any fields of the class. The function doesn't require any memory allocation. If the field `texto` was used in that function, then it would crash (as you see in your other test), because that memory isn't addressed. But here, there is no memory involved. Both `a` and `b` (and the function result for that matter) are allocated elsewhere outside of the class. Part of the instantiation process is allocating memory for each and every one of the fields in the object.

This is just coincidental. It's still highly discouraged to actually use something like this. If you feel the need to access the function without instantiation, then you should make it a class function instead.

Comment: You can still crash it without accessing any fields f.i. marking the method virtual. The compiler, then, has to determine the instance (which there is none) type.

Comment: I disagree this is coincidental. This feature is used in TObject.Free, which does not raise an AV if the object is nil. Indeed, it checks if Self <> nil. Any non-virtual and non-dynamic method is accessible as long as it does not touch any fields.

Comment: If a method doesn't use any fields of the instance, I tend to make it a static class function. That way any attempt to access an instance field (e.g. after a modifcation) will not compile.

Comment: @Rudy is absolutely right. Use a class method if the method doesn't (logically) depend on a particular instance.

Comment: @Silver: checking Self for **`nil`** is not the same as accessing the field of a non-existing object. But the coincidence here is that the method (as it is now) doesn't access any instance fields. So yes, it is coincidental that it doesn'r crash. Anyway, methods that don't touch instance fields should rather be made class methods, preferrably static.

Comment: I don't automatically make methods class methods which aren't touch class fields. I only make those methods class method which operate on or closely related to the class (and not to the object that the class represents).

Comment: @RM If a method doesn't access the instance, why should it be an instance method? Why have a parameter that is completely ignored?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan depends. Class method is relevant to the class but not what the class represents. E.g. a painter class which has 2 paint methods and one method can do it's job without accessing fields. I would not make that a class method just because it does not access any fields. I keep it as a normal method because it's operation is relevant to what the class represents (painter). In case e.g. this class has a method which returns how many instance of the class has been created then this method is relevant to the class itself so I make it class method.

Comment: IMMO by following this principle the class is easier to understand.

Comment: Let me try to explain it differently. My painter class is modelling a painter. To paint something I need to instantiate a painter and ask it to paint (if the painter does not exit it can not paint). So it have to be an instance method. This has nothing to do with how many instance fields the method actually needs to do its job. This is my way of thinking - I am trying to model the real word.

Comment: @RM but what you describe is a scenario where we can paint without a painter and so your analogy breaks down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in real world let's put a chair in a room. But do not put a painter. Can you have the painter paint the chair? No, because the painter does not exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you don't need to follow my analogy. But advice was given above to always make all methods to class method if they don't access a class field. It is important to comment that not everyone is following this rule and I think I made reasonable explanation why. I am not saying that this is the only way  to do it but it is unfair to say that my comment and analogy is useless. You could have just wrote that you disagree. These kind of comments you make discourage others to comment or answer on SO.

Comment: Just a note that my last comment was reflecting on a comment which has been since removed.

Comment: I hope my edit to the end of the answer helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: @RM. The analogy breaks down very clearly. You are saying that you can't paint without a painter. But in your supposedly analagous code you can paint without a painter. I don't agree with you. If that discourages you from commenting here, then that's for you to deal with.

Comment: @davidHeffernan your previous not nice comment which had been since deleted was discouraging. This one would have been nice except for the last sentence.

Comment: @RM. Well I can't imagine what I could have said but it seems to me that you are taking technical criticism personally

Comment: @davidheffernan How is the subject became me again?

Comment: @RM. The subject has always been technical from me. If you look through the comments it was you that wanted to talk about your feelings. I responded to that.