# Object.Create(nil) not necessary?

Tags: delphi

Why if I skip object creation, my code is still working ?
`AbUnzipper1.FileName := 'C:\MyFile.zip';` never raises an access violation at runtime.

This (simplified) code is from a DLL, without form to put components on.

```
uses AbArcTyp, AbUnZper,...
...
var
  AbUnZipper1: TAbUnZipper;
begin
  // AbUnZipper1 := TAbUnZipper.Create(nil);  COMMENTED !!!!!!!!
  AbUnzipper1.FileName := 'C:\MyFile.zip';
  AbUnzipper1.BaseDirectory := 'C:\temp\MyFolder';
  AbUnzipper1.ExtractOptions := [eoCreateDirs, eoRestorePath];
  AbUnzipper1.ExtractFiles('*');
  AbUnZipper1.Free;
end;
```

Comment: It is *undefined behavior* to access an object without creating it. You are just lucky your code didn't crash or corrupt memory

Comment: Exactly what i was wondering. Thank you Mr Lebeau.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi - why does this function work if the class is not created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866727/delphi-why-does-this-function-work-if-the-class-is-not-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code `AbUnZipper1` is an undefined reference (i.e. a pointer). Behaviour when you access it is undefined. It may point to valid memory, or it may point to invalid memory.

If the latter, when you attempt to use the reference you will encounter a runtime error, an access violation. If the former, then you will succeed in accessing the memory, but that memory belongs to something else in your program and you will corrupt it.

If your program runs without error then that is by chance. You will likely have corrupted memory elsewhere along the way.

Your code is wrong, and you should fix it by restoring `AbUnZipper1 := TAbUnZipper.Create(nil)`.

You should also make sure that you use `try / finally` in this code to avoid memory leak in case of exceptions.